# Numpy custom Cumsum function with upper/lower limits?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a numpy/pandas list of values:

```
a = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10000)
b = a/100
```

I want to apply a custom cumsum function, but I haven't found a way to do it without loops. The custom function sets an upper limit of 1 and lower limit of -1 for the cumsum values, if the "add" to sum is beyond these limits the "add" becomes 0.

In the case that sum is between the limits of -1 and 1 but the "added" value would break beyond the limits, the "added" becomes the remainder to -1 or 1.

Here is the loop version:

```
def cumsum_with_limits(values):
    cumsum_values = []
    sum = 0
    for i in values:
        if sum+i <= 1 and sum+i >= -1: 
            sum += i
            cumsum_values.append(sum)
        elif sum+i >= 1:
            d = 1-sum # Remainder to 1
            sum += d
            cumsum_values.append(sum)
        elif sum+i <= -1:
            d = -1-sum # Remainder to -1
            sum += d
            cumsum_values.append(sum)

    return cumsum_values
```

Is there any way to vectorize this? I need to run this function on large datasets and performance is my current issue. Appreciate any help!

---

**Update**: Fixed the code a bit, and a little clarification for the outputs:
Using np.random.seed(0), the first 6 values are:

```
b = [0.72, -0.53, 0.17, 0.92, -0.33, 0.95]
```

Expected output:

```
o = [0.72, 0.19, 0.36, 1, 0.67, 1]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `cumsum_with_limits` gives you the list of values such that their cumsum ever goes below -1 or above +1, right? So, what you want is that array of numbers, not the cumsum itself, is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct, the output is the list of values not the cumsum itself e.g. [0, 0.3, 0.6, , 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, -0.3, -0.6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -0.5], it can't go beyond 1 or -1

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of an input and expected output that showcases the way you handle all the bounds?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some version of reduceat that would do this for you. Just have to figure out how to phrase it.

Comment: Yep, input [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], output [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: That's not the result your current function gives.  That result can be gathered just using `np.clip(np.cumsum(x), -1, 1)`

Comment: Checked np.clip, using the example values [0.72,-0.53,0.17,0.92,-0.33,0.95] it returns [0.72, 0.19, 0.36, 1, 0.95, 1], it is only correct until it hits the first limit (the value after 1 should be 1-0.33 = 0.67 and not 0.95)

Comment: The problem is inherently serial - the value at one step depends on the value at the previous.  So it must be done with a loop.  The only question is whether you can implement that loop in compiled code or not (using stock numpy methods or a custom `numba` one).

Comment: @Franc. I have a way of doing it with fewer loops (iterating only over the clip points). Let me see if I can get numpy to vectorize that for you.

Answer (score 6):

Loops aren't necessarily undesirable. If performance is an issue, consider `numba`. There's a ~330x improvement without materially changing your logic:

```
from numba import njit

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10000)
b = a/100

@njit
def cumsum_with_limits_nb(values):
    n = len(values)
    res = np.empty(n)
    sum_val = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = values[i]
        if (sum_val+x <= 1) and (sum_val+x >= -1):
            res[i] = x
            sum_val += x
        elif sum_val+x >= 1:
            d = 1-sum_val # Remainder to 1
            res[i] = d
            sum_val += d
        elif sum_val+x <= -1:
            d = -1-sum_val # Remainder to -1
            res[i] = d
            sum_val += d
    return res

assert np.isclose(cumsum_with_limits(b), cumsum_with_limits_nb(b)).all()
```

If you don't mind sacrificing some performance, you can rewrite this loop more succinctly:

```
@njit
def cumsum_with_limits_nb2(values):
    n = len(values)
    res = np.empty(n)
    sum_val = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = values[i]
        next_sum = sum_val + x
        if np.abs(next_sum) >= 1:
            x = np.sign(next_sum) - sum_val
        res[i] = x
        sum_val += x
    return res
```

With similar performance to `nb2`, here's an alternative (thanks to @jdehesa):

```
@njit
def cumsum_with_limits_nb3(values):
    n = len(values)
    res = np.empty(n)
    sum_val = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = min(max(sum_val + values[i], -1) , 1) - sum_val
        res[i] = x
        sum_val += x
    return res
```

Performance comparisons:

```
assert np.isclose(cumsum_with_limits(b), cumsum_with_limits_nb(b)).all()
assert np.isclose(cumsum_with_limits(b), cumsum_with_limits_nb2(b)).all()
assert np.isclose(cumsum_with_limits(b), cumsum_with_limits_nb3(b)).all()

%timeit cumsum_with_limits(b)      # 12.5 ms per loop
%timeit cumsum_with_limits_nb(b)   # 40.9 µs per loop
%timeit cumsum_with_limits_nb2(b)  # 54.7 µs per loop
%timeit cumsum_with_limits_nb3(b)  # 54 µs per loop
```

Comment: @FrancWeser, No problem. It's probably because you mention you don't want a loop. But *sometimes* it's not necessarily a bad idea. For what it's worth, a specialized NumPy method is probably preferable, so please don't mark this as accepted until others have tried to figure it out.

Comment: I know I did misunderstood the question , so that downvote for me is fine , but why this answer get downvote as well ?

Comment: @W-B not sure, but I think your answer is the correct one.  The user posted an example input output above that actually matches what you were doing :P.  Very confusing

Comment: @user3483203 ummm, that is why I delete it :-) I am stepping away from unclear question

Comment: Nice. You can also reduce the loop body to just three lines `x = min(max(sum_val + values[i], -1) , 1) - sum_val; res[i] = x; sum_val += x` (not sure if slightly faster or slower).

Comment: @jdehesa, Thanks, similar performance to the second `numba` version fyi. I'll add it to the alternatives!

Comment: That's an amazing performance improvement. Thanks a lot! Curious if there are still ways to solve it without looping

Answer (score 5):

Start with a regular cumsum:

```
b = ...
s = np.cumsum(b)
```

Find the first clip point:

```
i = np.argmax((s[0:] > 1) | (s[0:] < -1))
```

Adjust everything that follows:

```
s[i:] += (np.sign(s[i]) - s[i])
```

Rinse and repeat. This still requires a loop, but only over the adjustment points, which is generally expected to be much smaller than the total number of array size.

```
b = ...
s = np.cumsum(b)
while True:
    i = np.argmax((s[0:] > 1) | (s[0:] < -1))
    if np.abs(s[i]) <= 1:
        break
    s[i:] += (np.sign(s[i]) - s[i])
```

I still haven't found a way to completely pre-compute the adjustment points up front, so I would have to guess that the numba solution will be faster than this, even if it you compiled this with numba.

Starting with `np.seed(0)`, your original example has 3090 adjustment points, which is approximately 1/3. Unfortunately, with all the temp arrays and extra sums, that makes the algorithmic complexity of my solution tend to O(n<sup>2</sup>). This is completely unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had already answered the generic question of "cumulative sum with bounds" in the past, but I can't find it.

This solution also uses `numba` and is a bit more general (custom bounds) and concise than the ones given by @jpp.

It operates on the OP's problem (10K values, bounds at -1, 1) in 40 µs.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumsum_clip(a, xmin=-np.inf, xmax=np.inf):
    res = np.empty_like(a)
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = min(max(c + a[i], xmin), xmax)
        res[i] = c
    return res
```

#### Example

```py
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10_000) / 100

>>> x[:6]
array([ 0.72, -0.53,  0.17,  0.92, -0.33,  0.95])

>>> cumsum_clip(x, -1, 1)[:6]
array([0.72, 0.19, 0.36, 1.  , 0.67, 1.  ])

%timeit cumsum_clip(x, -1, 1)
39.3 µs ± 31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Note: you can specify other bounds, e.g.:

```py
>>> cumsum_clip(x, 0, 1)[:10]
array([0.72, 0.19, 0.36, 1.  , 0.67, 1.  , 1.  , 0.09, 0.  , 0.  ])
```

Or omit one of the bounds (for example here specifying only an upper bound):

```py
>>> cumsum_clip(x, xmax=1)[:10]
array([ 0.72,  0.19,  0.36,  1.  ,  0.67,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.09, -0.7 , -1.34])
```

Of course, it preserves the original dtype:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 10)
>>> cumsum_clip(x, 0, 10)
array([ 2,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 10,  4])

>>> cumsum_clip(x, 0, 10).dtype
dtype('int64')
```